# Don't understand Java class definition containing an iterable of itself.

Tags: java, generics, iterable

I came across a class in our java project that is confusing for me to understand.
It implements the Iterable interface with a type parameter as it's self for that iterable. Could someone shed some light on to what this does and why it would be useful?

```
public class IndexRequest extends Request implements Cloneable, Iterable<IndexRequest> {
    public enum OpType {insert, update};

    protected Index index;
    protected Type type;
    protected boolean incomingAsArray;
    protected long timeToLive;
    protected String parent;
    protected String route;
    protected LinkedListMultimap<String, IndexRequest> iterable;
    protected String errorMessage;
    protected String stackTrace;
    protected String warnMessage;
    protected OpType opType = OpType.insert;
    protected long versionId;
    protected JsonNode previousDocument;
    protected boolean ignored;
    protected String resultCode;
    protected int retries = 0;
    protected boolean esUpsertFlag = false;
    protected String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public IndexRequest() {
        super();
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexRequest.class);
        this.requestJson = JsonNodeFactory.instance.arrayNode();
    }


    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public IndexRequest(String endpointPath, String requestId, String user, JsonNode requestJson, Map<String, String[]> requestParameters) {
        super(endpointPath, requestId, user, requestJson, requestParameters);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize our iterable version of this class
     */
    protected void initIterable() {
LinkedListMultimap <String, IndexRequest> contents = LinkedListMultimap.create();
        if (isArray()) {
            ArrayNode docsArray = (ArrayNode) getDocument();
            Iterator<JsonNode> docIterator = docsArray.iterator();
            while (docIterator.hasNext()) {
                IndexRequest is = this.clone(false);
                // generate a new id since this is a new wrapper around a particular doc
                is.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                is.setDocument(docIterator.next());
                contents.put(is.getId(), is);
            }

            iterable = contents;
        }
        else {
            iterable = LinkedListMultimap.create();                     
            iterable.put(getId(), this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an iterator for this index set
     * @return Iterator<IndexRequest> An iterator for this index set
     */
    public Iterator<IndexRequest> iterator() {
        if (iterable == null) {
            initIterable();
        }
        return iterable.values().iterator();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it looks like recursive structure so it make sense to iterate over its child / subparts. and making it `iterable` eg. allows it to participate in foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class that implements the ***Iterable*** can be used with the new for-loop. Here is such an example:

```
List list = new ArrayList();

for(Object o : list){
    //do something o;    
}
```

The Iterable interface has only one method:

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
  public Iterator<T> iterator();    
}
```

It is possible to use our own collection type classes with the new for-loop. To do so, our class must implement the java.lang.Iterable interface. and provide the implementation of `iterator` method , which you can see in your class is provided here :

> ```
>   /**
>      * Returns an iterator for this index set
>      * @return Iterator<IndexRequest> An iterator for this index set
>      */
>     public Iterator<IndexRequest> iterator() {
>         if (iterable == null) {
>             initIterable();
>         }
>         return iterable.values().iterator();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This class looks like it defines a node in a tree of such nodes.  Instances hold a map from `String`s to other instances of the same class:

```
    protected LinkedListMultimap<String, IndexRequest> iterable;
```

They also inherit from their parent class some sense of being / holding an array of other instances.  When they are iterated, they provide the values from their map or the elements of their array.